# Get Cell Format from Google Sheet API using getByDataFilter (filter by Tab Name) in PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a very large and complex Google Spreadsheet with many sheets within it. I need to get Cell formatting (like font colors) for all cells from just a subset of the sheets within this Spreadsheet, I am aware that I can get cell formatting using 'includeGridData'. I can get all of the data using spreadsheets->get without issue, but when I add 'includeGridData' to that like this:

```
$sheetMeta = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId,['includeGridData' => true]);
```

This results in the call running log and eventually timing out/running out of resources.

So thinking if I can filter on just the sheets that I want - Looking at the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter), using 'getByDataFilter' with 'include_grid_data'=>true to filter on the sheets might get me what I am looking for but I can not find a way to create the parameters to pass to getByDataFilter, I am trying this:

```
$body= json_encode(array('data_filters' => [], 'include_grid_data'=>true));
$response = $service->spreadsheets->getByDataFilter($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

which results in:

> Expected parameter of type
> 'Google\Service\Sheets\GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest'

Does anyone have an example of how to do use getByDataFilter with a filter body as a parameter in php?

Tried:

```
$body= json_encode(array('data_filters' => [], 'include_grid_data'=>true));
$response = $service->spreadsheets->getByDataFilter($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

Expecting Sreadseheet data with grid data. But got:

> Expected parameter of type
> 'Google\Service\Sheets\GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Also, based on the error that you have received, `$body= json_encode(array('data_filters' => [], 'include_grid_data'=>true));` I saw that `'data_filters' => []` doesn't have a specified parameter as stated on the [reference article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter#request-body) that you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get all cell data using the spreadsheets.get method by filtering while using ranges and "includeGridData":

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId, array('ranges' => ['Jobs Dashboard!A4:A','Jobs Dashboard!B4:B','Jobs Dashboard!E4:E','Jobs Dashboard!N4:N','Jobs Dashboard!P4:P'],'includeGridData'=>true ));
```

This is heavy on memory, but working. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Came here for the same issue, found out that an instance of the proper object should be created. Sending a JSON encoded body still caused an error in my case.

I solved like this:

```
$gridRange = new \Google\Service\Sheets\GridRange();
$gridRange->sheetId = 0;
$gridRange->startColumnIndex = 0;
$gridRange->endColumnIndex = 24;
$gridRange->startRowIndex = 0;
$gridRange->endRowIndex = 10;

$dataFilter = new \Google\Service\Sheets\DataFilter();
$dataFilter->gridRange = $gridRange;

$body = new \Google\Service\Sheets\GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest();
$body->dataFilters = $dataFilter;
$body->includeGridData = true;

$response = $service->spreadsheets->getByDataFilter($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

Comment: insane... how  something so simple can be done so complicated, Google is amazing

Answer (score 0):

As defined here in this [reference article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter#request-body), you will need to define your parameters under `'data_filters' => []` based on the request that you would want to fetch.

**You could try something like this:**

```
$body = json_encode(array("dataFilters"=>array("gridRange"=>array("sheetId"=>0,"startRowIndex"=> 1,"endColumnIndex"=> 10,"endRowIndex"=>10,"startColumnIndex"=> 1)),"includeGridData"=>true));
```

For `sheetId`, this can change depending on what sheet you are fetching, you can easily get this on the URL portion of the spreadsheet.

**Below is a sample request body:**

```
{
  "dataFilters": [
    {
      "gridRange": {
        "sheetId": 0,
        "startRowIndex": 1,
        "startColumnIndex": 1,
        "endRowIndex": 10,
        "endColumnIndex": 3
      }
    }
  ],
  "includeGridData": true
}
```

You can replicate this by using the API Explorer on the [reference article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter#request-body) as seen on the screenshot below. This is a sample json response.

[image]

You would just need to define the `gridRange` parameter, as well as the `sheetID`, `startRowIndex`, `startColumnIndex`, `endRowIndex`, and `endColumnIndex` if you would want to specify the range of the formatting you would like to get.

Comment: If you have any further questions, feel free to respond

Comment: Thank you for the info! I am getting Sheet ID now from this section of the spreadseet URL: #gid=1662454648

And here is my body which works when I test using the API Explorer on the reference article:  

{
  "dataFilters": {
    "gridRange": {
      "sheetId": 1662454648,
      "startRowIndex": 1,
      "endColumnIndex": 10,
      "endRowIndex": 10,
      "startColumnIndex": 1
    }
  },
  "includeGridData": true
}

However, when I create the body in php and try to pass that to "$service->spreadsheets->getByDataFilter" I still get the error:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Google\Service\Sheets\Resource\Spreadsheets::getByDataFilter() must be an instance of Google\Service\Sheets\GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest, string given 

Here is my php:

$body = json_encode(array("dataFilters"=>array("gridRange"=>array("sheetId"=>1662454648,"startRowIndex"=> 1,"endColumnIndex"=> 10,"endRowIndex"=>10,"startColumnIndex"=> 1)),"includeGridData"=>true));

$response = $service->spreadsheets->getByDataFilter($spreadsheetId, $body);

Do I need to set $body to be an instance of GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use just values function instead of getting all the properties.

Faster and will not run out of memory.

```
$spreadsheetId = '11111111111111111hgfdhdgfhgfdhdgfh';
$range = 'A1:Z65';
$service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$table = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range)->getValues();
```